# Replacing null value in SAS with next available value by group

Tags: arrays, loops, null, sas

I am trying to replace missing values that occur before the first non-null entry in SAS. I have the following data:

```
StudentID           Day          TestScore
Student001          0            .
Student001          1            78
Student001          2            89
Student002          3            . 
Student002          4            .
Student002          5            .
Student002          6            95
```

I'd like to modify the data so the null values are replaces with the next available non-null entry:

```
StudentID           Day          TestScore
Student001          0            78
Student001          1            78
Student001          2            89
Student002          3            95 
Student002          4            95
Student002          5            95
Student002          6            95
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data scores;
length StudentID $ 10;
input StudentID $ Day TestScore;
datalines;
Student001          0            .
Student001          1            78
Student001          2            89
Student002          3            . 
Student002          4            .
Student002          5            .
Student002          6            95 
;
run;

proc sort data = scores;
by descending day;
run;

data scores;
drop addscore;
retain addscore;
set scores;
if testscore ne . then addscore = testscore;
if testscore eq . then testscore = addscore;
run;

proc sort data = scores;
by day;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sort data = have;
  by id descending day ;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  retain last_score;
  if first.id then call missing(last_score);
  if not missing(score) then last_score = score;
  else score = last_score;
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by id day;
run;
```

FYI, this will NOT set the missing values if there are any after the last known score for a given ID.  i.e. if you had something like:

```
Student002          5            95
Student002          6            .
```

Then only records prior to day 5 for id 002 will get a value of 95. Is that a possible condition for you? If yes, this solution will require a slight modification

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DOW loop to identify the next non-missing score, and a subsequent DOW loop to apply the non-missing score.  The DOW approach does not require sorting and maintains the original row order.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id or not missing(score));
    set have;
    by id;
  end;

  _score = score;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    score = _score;
    output;
  end;

  drop _score;
run;
```

In SQL, presuming day ordering, the imputed value can be looked up in a correlated sub-query.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    id, day, 
    case 
      when not missing(score) then score
      else (select score from have as inner 
            where inner.id = outer.id 
              and inner.day > outer.day
              and not missing(score)
              having inner.day = min(inner.day)
            )
    end as score
  from have as outer;
```